# Print Strings with next line in Java (Zebra Line Mode)

Tags: java, android, printing, zebra-printers, bluetooth-printing

I want to print two strings using **Zebra printer** with **Line Mode**.

I have used **\n** as well as **String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");**

Still the Zebra Printer is not printing the two strings in different lines.

Here is my code

```
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
String mtest1= "test 1"+newline;
String mTest2= "test 2";
mmOutputStream.write(mtest1.getBytes(),0,mtest1.getBytes().length);
mmOutputStream.write(mTest2.getBytes(),0,mTest2.getBytes().length);
```

Kindly help me with this issue.
Want to print strings in separate line.

Comment: I have used both \n and separator. It is not taking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use \r\n. Here is the formatted code.

```
mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
String mTest= "\r\n"+"test 1"+"\r\n"+
            "test2";;

mmOutputStream.write(mTest.getBytes(),0,mTest.getBytes().length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use \& for new line

```
^FT78,76^A0N,28,28^FH\^FDHello\&World^FS
```

**OR**

```
^FB400,2,0,C^FO0,50
^FDHello\&World^FS
```

**Both Output**

Hello

World

For more information read this Java programming for Zebra Printers [document>>](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/java-example-for-network-printing.html).